# Parameterization of time stamp in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I’m new to Jmeter. I have a scenario like register multiple users one by one with different time stamp, not the same date, while registration of an website. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function which can return current/past/future dates and times in different formats:

[image: JMeter Timeshift Demo]

The date is being parsed as per [Duration.parse(CharSequence)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence) function.

See [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function) article for more information on the approach if needed